# How to stop a running Docker container from within the same terminal?

Tags: linux, docker

I've built a `Dockerfile` which ends with compiling my (Golang) code and then running the compiled binary:

```
# Compile my Go code
RUN go build -o bin *.go

# Run the binary
CMD /root/src/whisky/bin
```

After building the image (`docker build -t whisky .`) I run the image (`docker run --name whisky whisky_image`) and the program starts to give output in the terminal.

When I run the program from my laptop I can always stop it using `CTRL+C`, but now it's running inside the container and hitting `CTRL+C` doesn't do anything. The container simply keeps giving output and nothing stops.

I can still stop the container from another terminal `docker stop whisky`, but I guess there should be a nicer way.

Does anybody know the recommended way to stop the command in the container or stop the whole container from the same terminal?

[EDIT]

From the answers given I learned I can run the container in detached mode using `-d` and then tail the container logs using `docker logs container_id --follow`. Although that works I prefer to run the container directly (in non-detached mode) because then I can't make the mistake of running it in the background and forgetting about it.

Does anybody know how I can run the container in a way that I can stop it from the same terminal by hitting `CTRL+C`?

Comment: why not running it in deattached mode and see the logs from docker logs -f CONTAINER ?

Comment: how you start container? are you allocating tty `docker run -it my_image`?

Comment: If you run container attached to it the `Ctrl+C` stops the container.

Comment: What do you mean by "but now it's running inside the container and hitting CTRL+C doesn't do anything" ? What command are you using to be in this state?

Comment: @kramer65 have you tried `-it` as answers suggest? Does it help?

Answer (score 2):

you can use '-d'  --> in detached mode

[EDIT]
To add. After that you can tail to logs using

```
docker logs container_id --follow
```

Comment: Although this works, it doesn't actually answer the question. Would you have any idea why I cannot stop the running container if I start it in non-detached mode? I edited the question a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Allocate a pseudo-tty (`-t`) and then you can control output by hitting `CTRL+C`:

```
$ docker run --name whisky -t whisky_image
^C
```

But container will be still running, so add also stdin (`-i`):

```
$ docker run --name whisky -ti whisky_image
^C
```

But container will be still there (see `docker ps -a` - in exited status), so you may  add cleanup flag `--rm`:

```
$ docker run --name whisky --rm -ti whisky_image
^C
```

See [Docker run doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

you need to run your container using  `init`

```
docker run --init --name whisky whisky_image
```

then kill it using `Ctrl+C`

the `init`will start your program as `PID 1`

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned ealier, there is 2 possibilities, the first, detaching the process (`-d` option) or use a TTY with Interactive mode (`-ti` option).

The detached version will allow you to work and manage the instance, but won't let you down it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

The TTY version with an Interactive mode (`-i`) will.

So, `docker run -it` should do the trick

[Docker Run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) and [Docker Container process behaviors](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2016/01/dumb-init-an-init-for-docker.html#process-behavior-inside-docker-containers) can also help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Compile my Go code
RUN go build -o bin *.go

# Run the binary
CMD ["/root/src/whisky/bin"]
```

This is the exec form. in this form your executable is being called directly.
What you used is the shell form which starts your process with /bin/sh -c. This form does not automatically pass signals to the child processes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM golang

WORKDIR /go/src/app

ADD . .

# Compile my Go code
RUN go build -o bin *.go

# Run the binary
CMD /go/src/app/bin
```

#### Go program

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    for {
        fmt.Println("\nWHISKY TIME: ", time.Now().String())
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

#### Building the Container

```
╭─exadra37@exadra37-Vostro-470 ~/Developer/DevNull/stackoverflow  
╰─➤  sudo docker build -t whisky . 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/5 : FROM golang
 ---> c4d6fdf2260a
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /go/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ab35c58a3608
Step 3/5 : ADD . .
 ---> 320a51d3e579
Step 4/5 : RUN go build -o bin *.go
 ---> Running in 5db9f4a9cbe1
Removing intermediate container 5db9f4a9cbe1
 ---> e16b272606da
Step 5/5 : CMD /go/src/app/bin
 ---> Running in f66039aeb53a
Removing intermediate container f66039aeb53a
 ---> d453f9e10c49
Successfully built d453f9e10c49
Successfully tagged whisky:latest
```

#### Running the Container

```
╭─exadra37@exadra37-Vostro-470 ~/Developer/DevNull/stackoverflow  
╰─➤  sudo docker run -it --name whisky whisky                                                                                                                                                                137 ↵

WHISKY TIME:  2019-11-25 16:19:26.397705029 +0000 UTC m=+0.000041700

WHISKY TIME:  2019-11-25 16:19:27.399189969 +0000 UTC m=+1.001526690

WHISKY TIME:  2019-11-25 16:19:28.399392173 +0000 UTC m=+2.001728894

WHISKY TIME:  2019-11-25 16:19:29.399566682 +0000 UTC m=+3.001903403
^C%
```

As you can see I was able o stop it with `CTRL + C`, and I just needed to use the flags `-it`.

**The flags used:**

```
╭─exadra37@exadra37-Vostro-470 ~/Developer/DevNull/stackoverflow  
╰─➤  docker run --help | grep "\-t, \-\-tty" -                                                                                                                                                                 2 ↵
  -t, --tty                            Allocate a pseudo-TTY
╭─exadra37@exadra37-Vostro-470 ~/Developer/DevNull/stackoverflow  
╰─➤  docker run --help | grep "\-i, \-\-interactive" -
  -i, --interactive                    Keep STDIN open even if not attached
```

#### Restarting the container

```
╭─exadra37@exadra37-Vostro-470 ~/Developer/DevNull/stackoverflow  
╰─➤  sudo docker start -i whisky

WHISKY TIME:  2019-11-25 16:21:03.159420042 +0000 UTC m=+0.000047654

WHISKY TIME:  2019-11-25 16:21:04.161264182 +0000 UTC m=+1.001891819

WHISKY TIME:  2019-11-25 16:21:05.161470301 +0000 UTC m=+2.002097939
^C%
```

When restarting the container we just need to use the flag `-i`, and you are still able to stop it with `CTRL + C`.

**The flags used:**

```
╭─exadra37@exadra37-Vostro-470 ~/Developer/DevNull/stackoverflow  
╰─➤  docker start --help | grep "\-i, \-\-interactive" -
  -i, --interactive             Attach container's STDIN
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with my response to have been down-voted... I even provided a working example.

Answer (score -1):

To stop the whole container please use below commands.

```
 $ docker stop <container>
```

The **docker stop** command stops running Docker containers. 
It sends the SIGTERM signal to the running process inside the docker container and requests it to terminate.